# Automate basic calculations with residuals in R

Tags: r

I have some basic calculations I want to apply on residuals of a plm model but I am stuck on how to automate the steps for a lot of data.

Let's assume the input is a data.frame (`df`) with the following data:

```
Id          Year    Population  Y       X1          X2          X3
country A   2009    977612  212451.009  19482.7995  0.346657979 0.001023221
country A   2010    985332  221431.632  18989.3     0.345142551 0.001015205
country A   2011    998211  219939.296  18277.79286 0.344020453 0.001002106
country A   2012    1010001 218487.503  17916.2765  0.342434314 0.000990409
country B   2009    150291  177665.268  18444.04522 0.330864789 0.001940218
country B   2010    150841  183819.407  18042       0.327563461 0.001933143
country B   2011    152210  183761.566  17817.3515  0.32539255  0.001915756
country B   2012    153105  182825.112  17626.62261 0.321315437 0.001904557
country c   2009    83129   132328.034  17113.64268 0.359525557 0.005862866
country c   2010    83752   137413.878  16872.5     0.357854141 0.005819254
country c   2011    84493   136002.537  16576.17856 0.356479235 0.005768219
country c   2012    84958   133064.911  16443.3057  0.355246122 0.005736648
```

A model was applied and the residuals are stored:

```
    fixed <- plm(Y ~ Y1 + X2 + X3,
           data=df, drop.unused.levels = TRUE, index=c("Id", "Year"), model="within")
residuals <- resid(fixed)
```

In my next step, I want to calculate "weighted averages" of my residuals with:

[image: Residuals Formula]

with nit standing for the population in country i at time t and nt being the total population at t.

My approach so far is:

First I compute the total population nt for every year:

```
year_range <- seq(from=2009,to=2012,by=1)
tot_pop = NULL
for (n in year_range)
{
  tot_pop[n] = with(df, sum(Population[Year == n]))
}
```

Before taking the sum of the "weighted" residuals, my next step would be to automate the calculation of my "new" residuals:

```
res1 <- df$Population[1]/tot_pop[2009] * residuals[1]
res2 <- df$Population[2]/tot_pop[2010] * residuals[2]
res3 <- df$Population[3]/tot_pop[2011] * residuals[3]
...
res12 <- df$Population[12]/tot_pop[2011] * residuals[12]
```

Edit: Applying the solution of JTT to my problem, the last step would then be:

```
year_range1 <- rep(year_range, 3)
df_res <- data.frame(year = year_range1, res=as.vector(res))
aggr_res <- aggregate(df_res$res, list(df_res$year), sum)
colnames(aggr_res) <- c("Year", "Aggregated residual")
```

Is that correct?

I have tried the lapply function and a double "for-loop" without success. I don't know how to do this. Your help would be appreciated. If my question is unclear, please comment and I will try to improve it.

Comment: In your original formula you specified that i is the country, and the summation then goes over countries. Here you have aggregated for years, but shouldn't you rather aggregate for countries? If so, then just using e.g. `df_res <- data.frame(country = df$Id, res=as.vector(res)); aggr_res <- aggregate(df_res$res, list(df_res$country), sum)`should work.

Comment: @JTT hmm, I think my summation is correct. The result should be one value for each year. Each value being the sum of all the countries for that particular year.

Comment: Yes, I haven't been very perceptive today... In that case that should be it. Did that solve your problem?

Comment: @JTT Yes, it did! Thanks :)
Maybe you also know the answer to this (related) problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275633/aggregating-regression-residuals-from-a-plm-model-in-r 
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of a for-loop, you might want to calculate the total population using the aggregate funtion, e.g.:

```
a<-aggregate(df$Population, list(df$Year), sum)
```

Notice the column names of a (Group.1 and x).

Then you could match the results in `a` to the data in `df` using the `match()`-function. It gives the matching row numbers, which can be used to subset data from `df` to the division before multiplying with the residuals. For example:

```
res<-df$Population/a$x[match(df$Year, a$Group.1)]*residuals
```

Now you should have a vector of "new" residuals in object `res`.

Comment: Great! Thanks. The aggregate function really is the better way here. I added the last step to my question.